# foreach loop not working

Tags: php, foreach

i have a for loop as below , inside the loop if i print i am getting an output but when i print outside of a loop i just get single value.

```
        $sql = 'SELECT productID,is_senioramtper,senioramt,p.id_product as productid,p.price as price FROM ps_product as p join ps_damc_products as pd on p.id_product = pd.productID  where is_senior_active =1';
                  if ($allproducts = Db::getInstance()->Executes($sql))
                      foreach($allproducts as $prod){
                        $amount = array();
                        if ($prod['is_senioramtper'] == 1)
                        {                                                       
                            $amount[$prod['productID']]=$prod['senioramt'];

                        }

                        elseif ($prod['is_senioramtper'] == 2){

                            $peramt = $prod['senioramt'];
                            $cal = ($peramt*$prod['price'])/100;
                            $amount[$prod['productID']] = $cal;
                            }
                        }

                        $prodwiseamt =json_encode($amount);
                        echo"<pre>";
                    var_dump ($prodwiseamt);
```

i want to have results in $prodwiseamt outside of loop.what is the issue in this?

Comment: put the array declaration out side the foreach loop. $amount = array();

Comment: Are you sure `$allproducts` is an array ? Because it has to be an array to work with foreach

Comment: its already outside.

Comment: thanks @TarunUpadhyay it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = 'SELECT productID,is_senioramtper,senioramt,p.id_product as productid,p.price as price FROM ps_product as p join ps_damc_products as pd on p.id_product = pd.productID  where is_senior_active =1';
                          if ($allproducts = Db::getInstance()->Executes($sql))
                              $amount = array();
                              foreach($allproducts as $prod){

                                if ($prod['is_senioramtper'] == 1)
                                {                                                       
                                    $amount[$prod['productID']]=$prod['senioramt'];

                                }

                                elseif ($prod['is_senioramtper'] == 2){

                                    $peramt = $prod['senioramt'];
                                    $cal = ($peramt*$prod['price'])/100;
                                    $amount[$prod['productID']] = $cal;
                                    }
                                }

                                $prodwiseamt =json_encode($amount);
                                echo"<pre>";
                            var_dump ($prodwiseamt);
```

You are initializing `$amount` array in each iteration so the assigned value is lost.
Try this code

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ($prod['is_senioramtper'] == 1)
                    {                                                       
    $amount[$prod['productID']][]=$prod['senioramt'];

   }
   elseif ($prod['is_senioramtper'] == 2)
   {
         $peramt = $prod['senioramt'];
         $cal = ($peramt*$prod['price'])/100;
         $amount[$prod['productID']][] = $cal;
   }
```